# FCM(firebase cloud messaging) push notifications IN NEXTJS CREATING issues and not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, next.js, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, next.js13

I was recently implementing FCM in my nextjs 13 app router app which is my first app with nextjs, I'm new to ssr concepts so had a weird issue with the setup of fcm. I was following a fcm setup in nexjs guide on Medium blogs and it had a simple straight forward setup:

1. Create firebase.ts in utils with firebase config
2. Create a service worker in public directory with name firebase-messaging-sw.js that was listing to the background push.
3. Having onmessage event listener for foreground push listening.

I can't find the exact blog post but this is similar [FCM Medium blog](https://medium.com/@munnashisad/fcm-push-notification-in-next-js-app-using-custom-hook-d78494cb9e4f)

I had this setup and the push was working fine  in my local machine foreground and background but when i was trying to deploy the project in prod I had a stubborn build time error

> Firebase SDK error: the browser used for this does not supported firebase something like that.

I could not create a production build because every time my npm run build would fail.

After spending a lot of time here and there i finally found probably 50-60% of the solution to the problem which was, I had to add checks to my **firebase.ts** code to make sure is wasn't running on the server where the **firebase sdk** is not supported.

It sounds weird but in **nextjs** i think the code is checked for both ssr and csr during build time i think, please correct me of im wrong.

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import {getMessaging, getToken, onMessage} from "firebase/messaging"
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
// Placeholder values for server-side rendering
const placeholderFirebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: '',
    authDomain: '',
    projectId: '',
    storageBucket: '',
    messagingSenderId: '',
    appId: '',
  };
  
  let app;
  const createFirebaseFunctions = () => {
      if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
          const firebaseConfig = {
            apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
            authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
            projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
            storageBucket: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
            messagingSenderId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MESSAGE_SENDER_ID,
            appId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_APP_ID
          };
          
          // Initialize Firebase
           app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
           const firebaseMessaging = getMessaging(app);
          
          
           const  getTokenLocal = (setToken) => {
              return getToken(firebaseMessaging, {vapidKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_VAPID_KEY}).then((currentToken) => {
                if (currentToken) {
                  console.log('current token for client: ', currentToken);
                  setToken(currentToken);
                  
                  // Track the token -> client mapping, by sending to backend server
                  // show on the UI that permission is secured
                } else {
                  console.log('No registration token available. Request permission to generate one.');
                  setToken(null);
                  // shows on the UI that permission is required 
                }
              }).catch((err) => {
                console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token. ', err);
                // catch error while creating client token
              });
            }
          
            const  onMessageListener = () =>
            new Promise((resolve) => {
              onMessage(firebaseMessaging, (payload) => {
                resolve(payload);
              });
          });
          return { getTokenLocal, onMessageListener };
      
      }else {
          // Export placeholder functions for SSR
          const getTokenLocal = () => null;
          const onMessageListener = () => null;
        
          return { getTokenLocal, onMessageListener };
        }
  }

  const { getTokenLocal, onMessageListener } = createFirebaseFunctions();
  export { app, getTokenLocal, onMessageListener };
```

here is my final firebase.ts file after making the checks for restricting the code to client side and the build error was not there.

but im still not confident with this setup even though its working for forground push and not for background push.

if you are someone who has experience with nextjs 13 app router please help me out with the correct fcm setup that would not create these issues and will work properly for foreground and background push>
Thank you!